# Stopping a Python while loop in a text-based adventure game

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am writing a text based adventure game in python language and unfortunately I can't stop the game. I tried writing the code --->

```
def GAME_RESTART():
    i = input("would you like to play again?(y/n)")
    if i == "y":
        Game()
    elif i == "n":
        print_pause("YOU'VE COME TO AN END!")
        print_pause("Hopefully the game finds you well")
    while i != "y" and i != "n":
        print_pause("Incorrect input. Please choose (y/n)") *#print_pause is a function I defined already in the rest of the code*
        pass
        GAME_RESTART()
```

Any suggestions how to break the code to stop working?

I actually tried using the command break but it did nothing

Comment: Where did you use `break`? Why not `return` since you are in a function?

Comment: `GAME_RESTART()` calling `GAME_RESTART()` doesn't really make sense

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a loop. (That includes what I presume is mutual recursion if `Game` is what eventually causes `GAME_RESTART` to be called.)

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the code to make use of the `while` loop. There's no need for the function to call itself.

```
def GAME_RESTART():
    while True:
        i = input("would you like to play again?(y/n)")
        if i == "y":
            Game()
        elif i == "n":
            print_pause("YOU'VE COME TO AN END!")
            print_pause("Hopefully the game finds you well")
            break # exit the loop
        else:
            print("Incorrect input. Please choose (y/n)")
```

Comment: Actually thank u all for your help I am still a beginner in python but I used the quit() function to end the game